# Is there any way to integrate snap with crouton?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell-snap-framework, snapcraft, crouton

Unable to perform any successful Snapcraft program installs.

This is despite a successful command line install of snapd per instructions found at:
https://snapcraft.io/install/hello-world/ubuntu#install

1. Here is the output from the initial chroot entry:

```
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startxfce4 -n xenial
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/xenial...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 4.4.211-17203-gbe96242e05a2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 5 00:06:55 PDT 2020 x86_64
```

2. Here is the output from the xenial chroot command line:

```
➜ ~ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for killshot:
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
➜ ~ sudo apt install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
snapd is already the newest version (2.42.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
➜ ~ sudo snap install hello-world
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello-world: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
➜ ~
```

Thoughts?